# Which definitions of 'positive' and 'negative' apply?

Tags: grammaticality, legalese

> **negative** liberties: that
>   is, individual subjects were entitled to do whatever was not forbidden by the law.
>   ...
>   ... There
>   was, however, an alternative forum capable of challenging the substance of English law,
>   and one that was based on the assumption of **positive** rights rather than **negative** liberties.
>   That forum was the European Court of Human Rights (ECtHR).

Source: p 44, *The English Legal System 2012-2013*, Gary Slapper

Here, I guess that **positive** = expressed, publicised. From the stated definition, **negative** = implied, implicit, tacit. Am I right? Yet do these meanings consist with the dictionary's:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/positive
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases the stipulations are explicitly mentioned. The difference is that *positive* is like *whitelisting*, while *negative* is like *blacklisting*.

Blacklisting means that everything is **allowed**, except what is **forbidden**. 
Whitelisting means that everything is **forbidden**, except what is **allowed**.

So when your law is based on positive rights, your default state is that you are not allowed to do anything, except that what is allowed by law: you have the right to earn a living, the right to have a house, the right to form a political party, etcetera.

It is called *positive* because your rights are listed as positive sentences: you can do A, B and C.

Negative liberties are laws that restrict a default state in which  *you are allowed to do anything*. The laws then tell you that you are **not** allowed to  kill, steal, et cetera.

That is called negative because the restrictions are listed as negative sentences.

In practice many laws use both forms (for instance, in a constitution, rights are granted, and in a criminal lawbook, restrictions are listed). However, the interesting thing is to know the *basis*. In the Netherlands I know that nobody can be punished by the state for doing something that is not explicitly forbidden by law. So in fact, I am allowed to do anything, except what is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the meaning 1.1 applies:

> [Positive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/positive) 1.1 Expressing or implying affirmation, agreement, or permission
>
> [Negative](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/negative) 1.1 Expressing or implying denial, disagreement, or refusal

A **"positive right"** is expressed as *"you can do this"*. A **"negative right"**, however, is a prohibition, and is expressed as *"you can't do this"*. I would call a *"negative right"* an [oxymoron](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oxymoron), or at the very least [double-speak](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/doublespeak?q=double-speak).